# SQL Server multiple schema object issues

Tags: sql-server, schema, synonym, alter

I have database that has multiple schemas and objects under them. I want to consolidate the objects into one schema.

I tried

```
ALTER SCHEMA dbo TRANSFER <custom_schema>.<table_name>
```

I get an

> object already exists message

However, I can't see it in the Management studio and

```
SELECT * from dbo.<table_name>
```

returns

> object does not exist.

Looks like some system table entry is out of whack. I looked at sysobjects and it has only one entry for . Any suggestions on how to trouble shoot/ fix this issue is welcome.

Note: I can create a synonym

```
CREATE SYNONYM dbo.<table_name> FOR <custom_schema>.<table_name>
```

works fine

Comment: Did you create the synonym before trying to transfer?

Comment: No. I created it when I found that I could not do the ALTER SCHEMA... TRANSFER

Answer (score 14, accepted):

According to [this MSDN page](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/937757) your issue may be caused by a **duplicate primary key name**.  i.e. your table_name's primary key name conflicts with a primary key name already defined within some other table in dbo.

> To resolve this issue, rename the
>   primary key for the table that you
>   want to move. Use a name that does not
>   appear as a primary key in the
>   destination schema.

Comment: I ran into this problem today, changed the PK name, altered the schema, then changed the PK name back to its original name and it worked perfectly!

Comment: This could apply to names of any constraints on the table being moved, including default, foreign key, and check constraints. Since names of such constraints [must be unique within a schema](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19832399/303101), moving a table to a different schema will cause the above mentioned error if that would result in a constraint name clash. The error message produced by SQL Server is very unhelpful.