# Liquibase unique constarint is not applied for a column named 'name' but works for any other columns

Tags: java, postgresql, liquibase, liquibase-sql

I wanna make two columns unique and i've created changelist with two *addUniqueConstraint's* cause when i try to list required columns within one *addUniqueConstraint columnNames* section it ins't worked.

So, i've specified addUniqueConstraint for "setSpec" column and second for "name" column, but constraint is applied only for "setSpec" column and i still have possibility to insert entity with duplicated name value. Also i've tried to rename column from "name" to "set_name" but behaviour has left the same.

So now i am confused about making both columns unique. Can anybady suggest a solution or maybe point out to my mistake cause i dont think such big library can have such simple defects. Thank you. But here is an interesting thing, when i leave only one addUniqueConstraint section then any one of specified columns get the constraint.

Here is my table:

```
<changeSet id="2020-07-07--16-00-create-set-table" author="Illia Daliek">
    <createTable tableName="set">
      <column name="id" type="uuid">
        <constraints primaryKey="true" nullable="false"/>
      </column>
      <column name="name" type="varchar(255)">
        <constraints nullable="false"/>
      </column>
      <column name="description" type="varchar(1024)"/>
      <column name="setSpec" type="varchar(255)">
        <constraints nullable="false"/>
      </column>
      <column name="created_by_user_id" type="uuid"/>
      <column name="created_date" type="timestamptz"/>
      <column name="updated_by_user_id" type="uuid"/>
      <column name="updated_date" type="timestamptz"/>
    </createTable>
  </changeSet>
```

here is my try to add unique constraints

```
  <changeSet id="rename-column" author="Illia Daliek">
    <renameColumn tableName="set" oldColumnName="name" newColumnName="set_name"/>
  </changeSet>

  <!--this one works fine-->
  <changeSet  id="2020-08-28--11-00-add-unique-constraint-to-set.set_spec-column " author="Illia Daliek">
    <addUniqueConstraint  columnNames="setSpec"
                          constraintName="unique"
                          schemaName="${database.defaultSchemaName}"
                          tableName="set"/>
  </changeSet>

  <!--this one doesn't work-->
  <changeSet  id="2020-08-28--11-00-add-unique-constraint-to-set.name-column " author="Illia Daliek">
    <addUniqueConstraint  columnNames="set_name"
                          constraintName="unique"
                          schemaName="${database.defaultSchemaName}"
                          tableName="set"/>
  </changeSet>
```

Comment: What is the error you get?

Comment: Note that two unique constraints on one column each is something different than one unique constraint on two columns. But `columnNames="setspec, name"` should work to create a constraint on two columns

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give another `constraintName` to the second constraint. I don't think you can have two contraints with identical Names on a table

Comment: Thank you for answer but this didn't help

Comment: Hmm, ok. It doesn't hurt either: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1397671/can-there-be-constraints-with-the-same-name-in-a-db#:~:text=two%20different%20schemas%20in%20the,containing%20schema%20unless%20specified%20otherwise.&text=Index%20names%20must%20follow%20the%20rules%20of%20identifiers. Is there any error log you could share?