# alter table add bit column as case when

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, calculated-columns, alter

Hello I am adding a new column to my table

```
  ALTER TABLE MyTable ADD  Active  AS    CASE WHEN EndDate < getdate() then 0 ELSE 1 END
```

**How can I set the column to be a bit?** because by default it is an int32. 
What I tried is to use this

```
ALTER TABLE MyTable ADD  Active BIT AS    CASE WHEN EndDate < getdate() then 0 ELSE 1 END
```

because of some [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1947447/how-do-i-add-a-column-to-a-table-in-sql-server-that-doesnt-allow-nulls) answers. However it seems is not a good aproach what I am doing.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Cast it to `BIT`:

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.MyTable
(
    EndDate datetime2
);

ALTER TABLE MyTable 
ADD  Active AS  CAST(CASE WHEN EndDate < getdate() then 0 ELSE 1 END AS BIT)

SELECT c.name
      ,t.[name]
FROM sys.[columns] c
INNER JOIN sys.[types] t
    ON c.[system_type_id] = t.[system_type_id]
WHERE object_id = OBJECT_ID ('dbo.MyTable')

DROP TABLE dbo.MyTable;
```

[image]