# Preventing MySQL double insert

Tags: php, mysql, sql, schema

I have a table more or less looking like

```
Name | Lastname | ID | Date
```

Is there a way to prevent the database from running the insert function if a person which such `Name`, `Lastname` and `ID` already exists without running additional queries searching for him?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

add a `UNIQUE` constraint on the columns,

```
ALTER TABLE TableName ADD CONSTRAINT tb_uq UNIQUE (ID, LastName)
```

once it has been implemented, if you try to insert a value which ID and LastName already existed, it will throw an exception. example

```
INSERT INTO tableName (ID, LASTNAME) VALUES (1, 'hello') // ok
INSERT INTO tableName (ID, LASTNAME) VALUES (2, 'hello') // ok
INSERT INTO tableName (ID, LASTNAME) VALUES (1, 'hello') // failed
```

Comment: Seems to be just what I need! Thanks!

Comment: If you want the query to fail gracefully, you can also add a further clause "ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE ID = ID;" on the end.

Comment: I'd be inclined to leave it to fail ungracefully so that you can handle it within the application, but then again all depends on the users intentions

Comment: @Simonatmso.net yes, it all depends on the user `:)`

Comment: @JW out of interest any particular reason for CONSTRAINT instead of a UNIQUE KEY?  Have always used UNIQUE KEY myself but if there's a performance reason it could be good to knoe for future reference.  Unless the two are considered identical of course :)

Comment: @Simonatmso.net [What is the purpose of CONSTRAINT naming](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1397440/what-is-the-purpose-of-constraint-naming)