# Mysql Create Index Set As No Duplicates

Tags: mysql, constraints, unique-constraint

I have a table p_places that has two columns that are both foriegn keys that references parent tables:

```
mysql> create table p_places(
    -> user_id int not null,
    -> place_id int not null,
    -> FOREIGN KEY(user_id) references people(user_id) ON DELETE CASCADE,
    -> FOREIGN KEY(place_id) references places(place_id) ON DELETE CASCADE
    -> )engine=innodb;
```

I am trying to create a index for both of the columns so there can not be duplicate rows(there can be duplicate foriegn keys however...just not rows).

I tried:

```
alter table p_places add index(user_id+place_id no duplicate);

alter table p_places add unique index(user_id+place_id);

alter table p_places add unique index both_id(user_id+place_id);
```

But had no success. I would like try to do this with the alter table command for learning purposes rather than creating the table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are close to what you want.

```
ALTER TABLE p_places ADD CONSTRAINT tb_unique UNIQUE(user_id, place_id)
```

- [Purpose of Naming Constraint](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1397440/what-is-the-purpose-of-constraint-naming)

Comment: Purpose of naming constraint was my second question...thanks!