# SQL Foreign key to a table with a composite primary key

Tags: sql, key

I'm using derby db with NetBeans and I'm having some troubles with my tables:

I've `TABLE_A` and `TABLE_B` and i create them like this:

```
CREATE TABLE TABLE_A
                (
                FIELD_1 varchar(20),
                FIELD_2 varchar(50),
                FIELD_3 varchar(2),
                PRIMARY KEY(FIELD_1,FIELD_2),
                )
```

and

```
CREATE TABLE TABLE_B
                (
                FIELD_1 varchar(20),
                FIELD_2 varchar(50),
                FIELD_3 varchar(20),
                FIELD_4 varchar(25),
                PRIMARY KEY(FIELD_3),
                FOREIGN KEY(???) REFERENCES regioni(FIELD_1,FIELD_2)
                )
```

The question is: how can I link a `TABLE_B` record to an another `TABLE_A` record when `TABLE_A` has got a 2-fields primary key? What I have to put instead of "???"?

Thank you!!!

Comment: Might be a good idea to have a surrogate key for this

Comment: If your primary key is made up of two columns, then all your foreign key referencing it **must** also use all those columns.

Comment: Shouldn't that `REFERENCES regioni (...)` be `REFERENCES TABLE_A (...)` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use all child columns that match the parent PK

```
 ...
 FOREIGN KEY(FIELD_1,FIELD_2) REFERENCES regioni(FIELD_1,FIELD_2)
 ...
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this,

```
CONSTRAINT fk_tbl FOREIGN KEY (FIELD_1,FIELD_2) 
                  REFERENCES regioni(FIELD_1,FIELD_2)
```

---

Out of the scope of the question but may give some informations why naming constraint is important

- [What is the purpose of constraint naming](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1397440/what-is-the-purpose-of-constraint-naming)