# MySQLt Workbench Constraints

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

I am using MySQL Workbench to create my data models. When i try to export the sql. it creates the Constraints for the Foreign keys.

If there anyway i can prevent that to happen ?

What are the advantages of Constraints ?

Comment: [What is the purpose of constraint naming?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1397440/what-is-the-purpose-of-constraint-naming)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fail to see the problem there. According to the [MySQL Documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/create-table.html) you can [define foreign keys for your tables](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/create-table-foreign-keys.html) in your column definition list or in separate constraint clauses.

So this code:

```
CREATE TABLE ReferencingTable (
  id         INT PRIMARY KEY,
  other_id   INT REFERENCES ReferencedTable (id)
);
```

Is equivalent to this code:

```
CREATE TABLE ReferencingTable (
  id         INT PRIMARY KEY,
  other_id   INT,
  CONSTRAINT FOREIGN KEY (other_id) REFERENCES ReferencedTable (id)
);
```

The difference is just a syntactic one and shouldn't matter to you.

Of course, you can instruct MySQL Workbench to just not forward engineer your foreign keys. This is available both in the Export/Forward Engineering dialogs and as a checkbox when editing a given table's foreign key. Here's the option in the Export dialog:

[image]

Comment: can u please point out the option in export. am not able to figure which on it is