# foreign key reference syntax error

Tags: mysql, sql

I am having trouble creating members table with the following code. `check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'schoolID int NOT NULL FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES schools(schoolID),' at line 1`

What is wrong with the syntax?

Thanks!

```
CREATE TABLE schools (
    schoolID int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
    parentID int NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
    schoolname VARCHAR(199) NOT NULL,  
    active int NOT NULL,
    dateENTERED datetime NOT NULL
);
CREATE TABLE members
(
    memberID int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
    schoolID int NOT NULL FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES schools(schoolID),
    active int NOT NULL,
    dateENTERED datetime NOT NULL
);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
CREATE TABLE members
(
    memberID int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
    schoolID int NOT NULL ,
    active int NOT NULL,
    dateENTERED datetime NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT member_FK FOREIGN KEY (schoolID) REFERENCES schools(schoolID)
);
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/cea97)
- [Purpose of Constraint Naming](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1397440/what-is-the-purpose-of-constraint-naming)

you can also do it this way,

```
CREATE TABLE members
(
    memberID int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    schoolID int NOT NULL ,
    active int NOT NULL,
    dateENTERED datetime NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT member_PK PRIMARY KEY (memberID),
    CONSTRAINT member_FK FOREIGN KEY (schoolID) REFERENCES schools(schoolID)
);
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/286d9)

Comment: You may want to add a note about the in-line constraint definition bug