# Why primary key name is always "PRIMARY"?

Tags: mysql, sql, primary-key

I have MySQL server, version 5.7.25.

When I create a table, **specifying primary key** name e.g.:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `test` ( 
   `test`.`id` BIGINT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT , 
   `test`.`name` VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL ,
    PRIMARY KEY `pk_test` (`id`)
);
```

So when I call:

```
SELECT constraint_name FROM information_schema.table_constraints WHERE table_name = 'test'
```

I expect the value to be `pk_test`, however, the value is `PRIMARY`.

Why MySQL sets provided primary key name to `PRIMARY`?

Comment: Hmmm . . . Perhaps try `constraint pk_test primary key (id)` if you want to name the constraint.

Comment: That didn't work. Still `PRIMARY`.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen this one has a better  explanation: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31734857/mysql-primary-key-constraint-with-name