# UNIQUE name (column1, column2)

Tags: mysql, sql

I've seen this done on multiple occasions, and well, I don't understand it much.  Basically, what I do understand is that there is a constraint on the input of these columns, to use both of them as UNIQUE together, but what I don't understand is the purpose of `name`?  In most cases, the `name` field does not even match any columns in the table, so I wonder is it possible to query the database on the `name` or something?  What is the name used for exactly?

Example:

```
CREATE TABLE boards (
  id_board smallint(5) unsigned NOT NULL auto_increment,
  id_cat tinyint(4) unsigned NOT NULL default '0',
  child_level tinyint(4) unsigned NOT NULL default '0',
  id_parent smallint(5) unsigned NOT NULL default '0',
  board_order smallint(5) NOT NULL default '0',
  id_last_msg int(10) unsigned NOT NULL default '0',
  id_msg_updated int(10) unsigned NOT NULL default '0',
  member_groups varchar(255) NOT NULL default '-1,0',
  id_profile smallint(5) unsigned NOT NULL default '1',
  name varchar(255) NOT NULL default '',
  description text NOT NULL,
  num_topics mediumint(8) unsigned NOT NULL default '0',
  num_posts mediumint(8) unsigned NOT NULL default '0',
  count_posts tinyint(4) NOT NULL default '0',
  id_theme tinyint(4) unsigned NOT NULL default '0',
  override_theme tinyint(4) unsigned NOT NULL default '0',
  unapproved_posts smallint(5) NOT NULL default '0',
  unapproved_topics smallint(5) NOT NULL default '0',
  redirect varchar(255) NOT NULL default '',
  deny_member_groups varchar(255) NOT NULL default '',
  PRIMARY KEY (id_board),
  UNIQUE categories (id_cat, id_board),
  KEY id_parent (id_parent),
  KEY id_msg_updated (id_msg_updated),
  KEY member_groups (member_groups(48))
) ENGINE={$engine};
```

In here you can see `UNIQUE categories` where `categories` is the name, but it does not relate to any column name anywhere.  Can this be queried or something?  Sorry for the Stupid question here.  Just never understood this!

Comment: I'm not sure but it might be a composite key named categories

Comment: Its about `UNIQUE categories (id_cate, id_board)`.. And it's just a name ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The name is specified so that you can use it to modify/delete the UNIQUE constraint later. It also helps give a more readable name(as compared to the one that would be autogenerated by mysql) to the index, which can be useful for debugging later.

More [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1397440/what-is-the-purpose-of-constraint-naming).

Comment: Thanks for the answer, can you provide an example to modify/delete it using the `name` of `categories`?

Comment: `ALTER TABLE boards DROP INDEX categories` should let you delete the UNIQUE constraint.

Comment: Ok, thank you.  Guess it is not important unless you wanna lessen up the strictness of the table in the future, which is not very common in my case.